# How to implement WebView in QR Code Generator using react native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

[Invariant Violation: WebView has been removed from react-native.][1]

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ce7T9.png, https://snack.expo.io/@aboutreact/generation-of-qr-code-in-react-native?session_id=snack-session-ESXWizmjL
```

Comment: If you want to generate QRCode image by given value you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/rn-qr-generator module

Answer (score 0):

WebView have been removed from React Native Core. You should install the package to use it.

```
npm install --save react-native-webview
```

For IOS, need to do

```
cd ios && pod install
```

Use like

```
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
```

More details at 
[Package](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview)
and 
[Getting Started Guide](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started.md)

Comment: I had already installed Webview package but i didn't get to know how to implement webview in my program. My program doesn't consist of any webview code..  i will just give my code so you can take a look in it...https://snack.expo.io/@aboutreact/generation-of-qr-code-in-react-native?session_id=snack-session-ESXWizmjL